# Ionic 2 - Slides how to change pagination progress color?

Tags: ionic2

I have slide where I set the `paginationStyle="progress"` how can I change the color of the progressbar?

```
<ion-slides #exercisesSlider pager paginationType="progress">
```

Could somebody provide me a way to change the color of the progressbar?

Answer (score 2):

Ionic uses Swiper API slides. So you can select using class names `swiper-pagination-progress` and `swiper-pagination-progressbar` like this:

```
.swiper-pagination-progress .swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background:red;
}
```

Comment: You only need ".swiper-pagination .swiper-pagination-progressbar" for the rule and the second half changes depending on the type of pager (e.g. .swiper-pagination-bullet for bullets/default)

Answer (score 1):

Using only the CSS borders worked for me :

```
.swiper-pagination-progressbar-fill {
  border: 2px solid rgba(175, 240, 122, 0.719);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and maybe obvious follow up from the answer from @Surya Teja .  If you separate the classes you can control which color for each part of the progress bar.

```
.swiper.pagination-progress {
    background-color: red
}
.swiper-pagination-progressbar {
    background-color: white
}
```